# Length of single player campaign in the Assassin's Creed series?

Tags: assassins-creed

Approximately how long is the single player campaign in each of the various Assassin's Creed games, for both completionist as well as story-only runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reasonably useful site (which will get more useful as people submit more times): [How Long to Beat](http://howlongtobeat.com/).

The overall averages for Assassin's Creed, AC2, and Brotherhood are currently at about 16, 35, and 24 hours respectively.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing 100% completion for AC:Brotherhood. I'm almost done and at 60 hours of gameplay. I'd say that I'm a decent enough player, so I estimate that 100% completion is anywhere from 60-80 hours for experienced to casual gamers. Beginners/younger audiences could take over 100 hours since gaining 100% synchronization on some missions can be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

- AC: 11 hours
- AC2: 18 hours/24 hours with side missions
- ACB: 15 hours/40 hours with side mission
- ACR: 9 hours/ 14 hours plus side mission

Which is the best (this is just my personal opinion)?

- AC: the most challenging game with most realistic combat. The whole game is gameplay even the story sections. Good story too.
  Can get repetitive though
- AC2: best story better levels new equipment
  But the combat is awful
- ACB: is in my opinion the best Ac game 
  Since it has the most content , multiplayer
  and best side missions plus a kill streak improved combat
- ACR: Best graphics great conclusion to Altair and Ezio. Hook blade and bombs and a interesting Desmond journey portal like gameplay are fun. It is shorter than ACB and feels like it is like a copy paste of ACB too.

Answer (score 1):

Story completion wise the first one is about 8 to 9 hours long, the second one is longer 14-15 hours.

Now this is a bit subjective since it depends on your skill level for an action game. I played both games on the console and the gamepad gives you a bit of more help than the keyboard-mouse combination.